Kali won't boot up after VirtualBox installation
I needed to run a Windows virtual machine in Kali Linux, so I set it up in VirtualBox. The Windows installation had an error, so I shut my machine down and went to bed. The next day I tried to boot it, and it showed a black screen with a blinking underscore in the top left corner. My hardware seems fine as it runs Windows 10 from a different drive without an issue. How can I fix it?

Running a Windows VM on Kali?! I haven't heard of this before and I don't think it'd be recommended!

Did you mean the host OS has a problem?

What Do you mean @security_paranoid? Why isn't it recommended?

No, @pico. The host OS is Kali and has no issues.

besides not booting as of recently, as I explain above.

That sounds like a possible hardware fault: it appears your Kali disk may have failed. Could you boot from a live Linux media with the Kali disk plugged in, and then try checking and mounting the filesystems from the Kali disk? If successful, try reinstalling the bootloader, as a localized disk fault may have corrupted one of the bootloader's blocks. You might also use smartctl -x on the Kali disk to see if it has detected internal errors or is at the end of its life.

The host OS being Kali is an issue in and of itself, but I concur with @telcoM that you're probably (hopefully) looking at a hardware fault. Because if you're not, then whatever you used to set it up in VirtualBox allowed the installation process to leak to the real system and do some real damage, and that sounds spectacularly bad.
